# Converting a d3.map quickly to an array of values

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

I have a d3.map (Hash) called `data`.

```
AUT: Object
BEL: Object
CHE: Object
CZE: Object
DEU: Object
```

I want to access a specific value (`specificValue`) of each object and put it in a simple array `var values = [2,3,335,2,...]` in order to dynamically compute a color scale.

I came up with the below solution but don't it's elegant because I have to traverse the whole hash. Isn't there a shortcut function or something for doing this?

```
 var values = [];
 data.forEach(function(k,v){
         values.push(v.specificValue);
 });     


var quantize = d3.scale.quantile()
        .domain(values)
        .range(colorbrewer[COLORSCHEME][COLORCLASSES].slice(1));
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for here. You already have it down to a single line of code and you have to traverse all objects to gather the information you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found possible solution, using d3.entries and array.map:

```
d3.entries(data).map(function(d){return d.value.specificValue})
```

Comment: Thanks. May I ask, is this the definite way of doing this, or have you found another way?